# Windows Defender Firewall, why these defaults?

Tags: windows-defender

For some time now these are the default settings WD propoes to me each time a process tries to connect to network for the first time.

The picture is in italian but it substantially asks for forbidding communication on private networks but letting them on public ones.

Only to me does it goes against common sense?

[image: default Windows defender settings]

Comment: IIRC it will check the checkbox for the type of network you're currently connected to

Comment: @gronostaj yep, pretty sure that's why.